# style.css in css directory (i.e. not in theme root)

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WordPress and this is my first attempt to migrate a static website to WordPress. The websites layout must remain unchanged so I intend to develop a theme for it.

I'm used to having css files in the css directory, but the [WordPress Theme Development page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates) states that there has to be a style.css in the theme root.

Can I setup WP to get css/style.css instead? What is the recommended way to organise css files in WP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wordpress' `wp_enqueue_style`.

```
function addMyScript() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my-style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addMyScript');
```

Just remember that you still need to have a `style.css` inside your theme root, even if it only has the details about the Theme in the form of comments.

Please refer to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Thank you. I was only aware of wp_enqueue_script(), not wp_enqueue_style().

Comment: Lack of inspiration (form the Wordpress team) if you ask me. They could have use a info.txt / info.json for the details regarding the theme and not enforcing people to put the style in the root. "if you don't like it, make a better one" :)